# PHP remove sub-array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that is returning dynamic values as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 1234
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 9876
    )

)
```

Problem is that I want to find out what array key user_id 9876 has, but because user_id is a sub array I can't simply do an array flip and then look it up like that. I tried doing an array flip method like below but the array flip doesnt work

```
$fliparray = array_flip($original);
echo $fliparray['7876'];
```

Comment: use array column to have a flatten array with all the user id values, then flip it to make it keys

Comment: `$lookupArray = array_combine(array_column($original, 'user_id'), array_keys($original));`

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$arrId = array_column($arr,null,'user_id');
```

you get an array of the form

```
array (
  1234 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => 1234,
  ),
  5678 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => 5678,
  ),
)
```

You can delete entries directly by use id.

```
unset($arrId[1234]);
```

If necessary, you can with

```
$numArr = array_values($arrId);
```

return an array how

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => 5678,
  ),
)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/lBcqK